# How to enable PPPoE Passthrough in DS-Link WR151DN

Tags: router, wireless-router, adsl-router, pppoe

My ISP provides the internet via PPPoE and if I enter the user name and password in its connection wizard, it can't connect to the ISP server.

As I learned, it requires PPPoE Passthrough (aka PPPoE Relay), but I can't find any settings in the routers configuration.

Can you help me to find the required setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This router is very low-end so it **doesn't have a PPPoE Passthrough feature.** Unfortunately, I had to return it to the shop.

Answer (score 0):

DS-Link WR151DN is router with wireless. Usually PPPoE configured in router itself (in web interace), but not from computer. Whu You want to configure PPPoE on PC?

Comment: You misunderstood me, I referred to the wizard of the router. It seems PPPoE and PPPoE with Passthrough are not the same and _in the router_ I can't find the PPPoE Passthrough setting.

Comment: Yes. I don't understood until now. Lets assume You enabled PPPoE passtrough on Your router and establish PPPoE connection from Your PC to ISP. You planning to use Internet only on this one PC?

Comment: Or Your ISP require to establish more that one PPPoE connection to acccess different resource kinds?

Comment: I intend to use the Wifi as well. The problem is that I don't know if there is a Passthrough setting in my router. I can't find it...

Comment: Highly possible there no PPPoE passtrough. (I cant easily fing manual for this router. http://www.ds-link.com.hk/products/wireless-router/ds-wr151nd-wireless-router-with-detachable-antenna) But possible there some similar feature, like "PPPoE relay"? And I still not understood why You need such feature.

Comment: I can't find PPPoE Relay, either. I need that because when I don't use the router, the internet works okay but when I use the router and enter the user name and password in its wizard, it says, it can't find the PPPoE server. The ISP _requires_ a router that has PPPoE Passthrough.

Comment: I suspect You misunderstood what is primary usege scenario of router. Generally, if router used, PPPoE session established not from PC, but from router itself, and then routed give access to Internet to all PCs an other devices connected to it.

Comment: I know that. But the router can't establish a connection unless it has PPPoE Relay. The PC has nothing to do with that. The ISP requires a router that supports PPPoE Relay.

Comment: No, PPPoE relay or PPPoE passtrough definitely not necessary to establish connection from the router itself. Its neccessary to establish PPPoE connection trough the router. May be there just a bug in connection wizard and You need to configure router manually?

Comment: The "Wizard" where You get the error, is router setup wizard or OS PPPoE connection wizard?

Comment: The wizard is the router's PPPoE wizard. I tried it manually but still not working. The ISP has a tutorial of how to set the Relay in a D-Link router. So they definitely require it.